# Regex in Ruby for multiple splits in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I need some advice perfecting a regex. I'm trying to split a string into three pieces with a single expression. Lines come from a text file in a format like so:

```
25 red delicious apples at 0.75
```

where the first part is the quantity, the second is the item name, and the third is the price per item. The code I'm using is this:

```
File.open('basket.txt').each_line do |line|
  item = line.split(/(\d+)\s|\sat\s/, 3)
```

This splits a string where I want it, but it creates an item array with length four (the first index contains `nil`). I also want to get rid of the newline character at the end of the float.

Comment: i personally like regex, but i will prefer not to use one in this case. i will just do

`words = line.split`

`quantity = words.shift`

`price = words.reverse.shift`

`name = words.join(" ")`

Comment: Oh, I forgot the 'at' in the string. That was my second marker.

Comment: in that case i will do:

`words = line.split;`

`quantity = words.shift;`

`price = words.reverse.shift;`

`words.reverse.shift;`

`name = words.join(" ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use match instead of split for this task. This way you will be able to get the groups more accurately. For instance if we assume there are no numbers in the name of the product:

```
s = "25 red delicious apples 0.75"
m = s.match(/(\d+) ([^\d.]+) ([\d.]+)/)
m[1]
=> "25"
m[2]
=> "red delicious apples"
m[3]
=> "0.75"
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach, but I had to edit the string - there's an 'at' in it. Can I reject the 'at' somehow? And I don't quite understand the expression - how is the middle capturing the string?

Comment: The middle captures anything but digits and dot.

Comment: oh, i see. ^ that is the negation thing. hmm. I like that except I'm not sure how to eliminate the ' at ' can I just stick the \sat\s someplace?

Comment: yes you can do that. For instance: `m = s.match(/(\d+) ([^0-9.]+)\sat\s([0-9.]+)/)`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did. I feel like I uglified your expression, but it works like a charm.

Comment: @pguardiario true will fix that. In fact I have no idea why I used 0-9 :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
txt = "25 red delicious apples 0.75"
pattern = Regexp.new('(?<=\d)\s|\s(?=\d)')
puts txt.split(pattern)
```

or with irb:

```
'25 red delicious apples 0.75'.split(/(?<=\d)\s|\s(?=\d)/)
```

with "at":

```
'25 red delicious apples at 0.75'.split(/(?<=\d)\s|\sat\s(?=\d)/)
```

An example with your loop:

```
pattern = Regexp.new('(?<=\d)\s|\sat\s(?=\d)')
File.open('basket.txt').each_line do |line|
  items = line.split(pattern)
end
```

Comment: Beautiful expression.

Comment: ugh, I just had to edit the question though, I forgot the 'at' in the string. Otherwise, it would've worked

Comment: What does The first part `?<=` do? And also this part: `?=`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: `(?<=..)` and `(?=..)` are lookaround assertions. These perform only checks without matching. The first is a lookbehind (preceded by ..), the second is a lookahead (followed by ..). More informations here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte everyday I learn something new. This is really cool! Thanks for the link :)

Comment: What is the difference between how these are read in a file vs irb. I've been banging my head against why i need \  but it looks like quotes and declaring the regex work too?

Comment: @EleMunjeli: Sorry, there is no differences, I wrote 'with irb' only to write it as a "one-liner"

Comment: Yes, that's how I like it. But I copy-pasted and my IDE is making errors at me. I have to quote it or what?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's still not working for me. Is Regex part of Ruby core? I'm getting a syntax error on all of these, but not on my original. Looks like this:in `initialize': undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=\d)\s|\sat\s(?=\d)/ (RegexpError)

Comment: You are obviously a Rex Regex, but Strandjev's answer ran for me. I will definitely study some more of this though. Thanks for your inspiration.

Comment: @EleMunjeli: Strandjev's answer is good too. I'm not a "Rex Regex", but you can find RexEggs here: http://www.rexegg.com/

Comment: looks like unnecessary lookaround to me.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should use a pattern matching instead of `split`.

```
line = "25 red delicious apples at 0.75\n"
line.match(/(\d+)\s+(.*)\s+at\s+(\S+)/).values_at(1, 2, 3)
# => ["25", "red delicious apples", "0.75"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p "25 red delicious apples 0.75".partition(/[\D\s]+/)
#=> ["25", " red delicious apples ", "0.75"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'25 red delicious apples at 0.75'.scan(/[0-9]+\.?\d*/) #=> ["25", "0.75"]
```

Comment: THis won't match single digit numbers for example.

Comment: Good catch. You were right. Changed `+` to `*` to match single digit.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
'25 red delicious apples at 0.75'.scan /(\d+[.\d]+) (.*) at (\d+[.\d]+)/
#=> [["25", "red delicious apples", "0.75"]]
```